# How to to show more than 4 columns of custom VisualForce page in Dashboards?

Tags: dashboard

I have created a Custom visual force page with around 7 columns and I am trying to display that in the Dashboards but when I do that half of the page is not visible.  Is there a way I can increase the width of the Dashboard layout to fit in my page or is there a way I fit in my VF page with 7 columns in the Dashboard layout?

Regards,
Manju

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the width of Dashboard page, However you could try to minimize font size in your Visualforce Page or Instead of showing 7 columns, you could show its as a row just like SFDC shows list view in Salesforce1 app.